# How can convert number given in parenthesis with negative number in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with rows having a string like:

```
{"Manufacture":"1920","Comapany":"(BMW)","Loss":"(20)","price":"93"}
{"Manufacture":"1911","price":"20","shutdown":"(13)"}
```

I want to convert **(number)** entry with **-number**
for example in first-row entry output will be

```
{"Manufacture":"1920","Comapany":"(BMW)","Loss":"-20","price":"93"}
```

Entry for loss is **(20)** which is converted to **-20**

same goes for second row entry

```
{"Manufacture":"1911","price":"20","shutdown":"-13"}
```

Comment: show what you tried?

Comment: I have tried with regex but able to find the pattern only confusing with the conversion task Details["Column"].str.replace(r"\(\d+\)", "-\d+")

Comment: str.replace will replace my findings with predefined input only

Comment: Do you want your shutdown and loss values of the type integer or string?

Comment: all the things will be as it just wherever any digits inside brackets, convert it into negative. example (23) will be -23.

Comment: values inside strings are not fixed. there are multiple values as shutdown and loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", s)
```

---

**Example:**

```
s = str({"Manufacture":"1920","Comapany":"(BMW)","Loss":"(20)","price":"93"})
st = str({"Manufacture":"1911","price":"20","shutdown":"(13)"})
```

---

```
res = re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", s)
```

---

**res:**

```
"{'Manufacture': '1920', 'Comapany': '(BMW)', 'Loss': '-20', 'price': '93'}"
```

---

```
result = re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", st)
```

---

**result:**

```
"{'Manufacture': '1911', 'price': '20', 'shutdown': '-13'}"
```

### Edit:

**Let say your df is:**

```
     0
0   {"Manufacture":"1920","Comapany":"(BMW)","Loss":"(20)","price":"93"}
1   {"Manufacture":"1911","price":"20","shutdown":"(13)"}
```

---

```
def num2neg(row):
    return re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", row)

df[0] = df[0].apply(num2neg)
```

---

**df:**

```
    0
0   {"Manufacture":"1920","Comapany":"(BMW)","Loss":"-20","price":"93"}
1   {"Manufacture":"1911","price":"20","shutdown":"-13"}
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I am also working on re.sub module to complete the task. i have to pass our data frame in a loop and apply this kind of logic to get the answer. if you have any idea that how can pass my dataframe column which i have all these rows having string values without using loop, please suggest.

Comment: you will use `df[column name].apply(your_function)`

Comment: check the edited answer. Closed the question if any of the answer helps.

Comment: I have also implemented the same logic                                                                
def conver(words):
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        word = str(word)
        new_word = re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", word)
        new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words

Comment: any error you are getting? without loop solution would be using apply

Comment: I can't show you the DataFrame, sorry about that. i am trying to process on this thing with numbers with commas also. example (233,455).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210151/discussion-between-rahul-semwal-and-pygirl).

Comment: re.sub(r"\((\d+.*?)\)", r"-\1", s), this on helped. Thanks Pygirl.